# My laptop's touchpad behaves like arrow keys

Tags: laptop, touchpad

I just purchased a Lenovo Ideapad 110 from a refurbished computer shop. On some applications such as Discord or even when trying to navigate the start menu, trying to scroll with my touchpad results in the laptop thinking I'm pressing my arrow keys. I can't seem to find this issue anywhere online or anywhere in the settings. Someone please send help, it's really annoying not being able to navigate things.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Lenovo support site for your model, find the Lenovo Software Update app.

Download it, run it and update all drivers. Be sure it picks up the Synaptics app for the Touch Pad.

Do this, restart and test.

If the touch pad continues to act strangely, return it to where you purchased it and have it repaired / replaced.